# Best way to replicate SQL "update case when..." with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, str-replace

I have this sample data set

| City |
| --- |
| LAL |
| NYK |
| Dallas |
| Detroit |
| SF |
| Chicago |
| Denver |
| Phoenix |
| Toronto |

And what I want to do is update certain values with specific values, and the rest of it I would leave as it is.

So, with SQL I would do something like this:

```
update table1
set city = case 
when city='LAL' then 'Los Angeles'
when city='NYK' then 'New York'
Else city
end
```

What would be the best way to do this in Pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `replace` on the City column:

```
df['City'] = df['City'].replace({"LAL": "Los Angeles", "NYK": "New York"})
```

output:

```
          City
0  Los Angeles
1     New York
2       Dallas
3      Detroit
4           SF
5      Chicago
6       Denver
7      Phoenix
8      Toronto
```

Comment: Hey @mozway ,may I ask a follow up , not to open a new question ? So, basically the same thing, but with multiple `in` conditions. Let's say I want to add a new column called  `df[state]="ABC"`  and now I want to update it according to city. So something like `when city in ('Houston','Dallas') then 'Texas', when city in ('Los Angeles','San Francisco') then 'Cali'`

So, expanding the question:

1. How to use multiple input values?
2. How to do it based on other column values?
3. How to set `else` value?

Comment: @botafogo use `map`:`df['State'] = df['City'].map({'Houston': 'Texas', 'Dallas': 'Texas', 'Los Angeles': 'California', 'San Francisco': 'California'})`

Comment: thanks! 
And one more if I may (sorry), how to set `else` value to be `ABC` instead of `NaN`

Comment: but is there a way to use multiple input arguments? 
e.g. if I have 20 cities from one state, you proposed `'Houston': 'Texas', 'Dallas': 'Texas'` 


But is it possible to do it something like this `('Houston', 'Dallas'): 'Texas'`  , is something like that possible?

Comment: Well you can use first a dictionary like `d = {'State1': ['City1', 'City2'], ...}` then rework using `{state: c for state, cities in d.items() for c in cities}`

Answer (score 1):

You can directly replace the values like this:

```
replacement_dict = {"LAL": "Los Angeles", "NYK": "New York"}
for key, value in replacement_dict.items():
    df['City'][df['City'] == key] = value
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace it using [`replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html). One option ist to define a dict.

Example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'City':["LAL","NYK","Dallas","Detroit","SF","Chicago","Denver","Phoenix","Toronto"]})
df.replace({"LAL": "Los Angeles", "NYK": "New York"})
```